# DateTime + long (hrs) with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How could i add (DateTime?) and (long?) in C#, where long is hrs.
Result expected in DateTime

Comment: possibly shouldn't be using long?s: use timespans maybe?...

Comment: DateTime.AddHours(); dont do the job ?

Comment: could it be possible with cultureInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        long hours = 44;
        var dt2=dt.AddHours(hours);  // uses an implicit cast from long to double
                                     // use "(double)hours" for an explicit cast
```

** Nullable Version **

```
        DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
        long? hours = 44;
        if(hours==null) hours=0;
        DateTime? dt2 = (dt == null) ? null : (DateTime?) ((DateTime) dt).AddHours(hours);
```

** Nullable Version (compact) **

```
        DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
        long? hours = 44;
        DateTime? dt2 = (dt == null) ? null : (DateTime?) dt.Value.AddHours(hours??0);
```

** Nullable with if statement **

```
        DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
        long? hours = 44;
        if(hours==null) hours=0;
        DateTime? dt2 = null;
        if (dt == null) 
            dt2 = (DateTime?) ((DateTime) dt).AddHours(hours);
        else 
            dt2 = null;
```

---

Follow up:

In the other answers, I liked the use of .Value (which looks a little cleaner than a cast), but this doesn't remove the need to check for null in the hours parameter.  btw: I tried one of the other .Value answers and got Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long?' to 'double' -- i.e. you can't forget the null check.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need the explicit cast to `double`, passing `hours` directly will work fine; secondly, you need to assign the results of the `AddHours` call to something: for example, `DateTime dt2 = dt.AddHours(hours);`

Comment: I believe both are `Nullable` types mentioned

Comment: yw.  Got to thank LukeH and V4Vendetta for pointing out my previous ommissions though.

Comment: Note that you could get rid of the `if (hours == null) hours = 0` and `hours ?? 0` checks by using `hours.GetValueOrDefault()` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx

Comment: @LukeH: isn't the default of a nullable long null?

Comment: @sgtz: It depends on what you mean by the default. `default(long?)` is indeed null, but `someNullableLong.GetValueOrDefault()` will be 0 if `someNullableLong` is null (basically returning the default value of the underlying type).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myNullableDate != null && myNullableHours != null)
{
    myNullableDate = myNullableDate.Value.AddHours((double)myNullableHours) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out on these lines

```
DateTime? dt2 = DateTime.Now;
long? lng = 5L;
if (dt2.HasValue)
   dt2 = dt2.Value.AddHours(lng ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `DateTime` is `myDt` and your long is `myLong`, this should work:

```
myDt.AddHours((double)myLong);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime datetime;
long hours = 123;
// ...

datetime = datetime.AddHours((double)hours);
```

Note that AddHours takes a double, so we need to cast it to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
long? hours = 1;
DateTime? d = new DateTime?();
d.Value.AddHours((double) hours);
```